# Why is my 1.3Gbps rated Wi-Fi speed only achieving about half of my 80Mbps ISP speed?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

Here's my equipment:

- With my ISP (CenturyLink) I have 80Mbps down and 10Mbps up.
- ZyXEL C2100Z Modem/Router with AC2050 Dual Band Wi-Fi (1.7Gbps 5GHz, 300Mbps 2.4GHz).
- TP-Link Archer C9 with AC1900 Dual Band Wi-Fi (1.3Gbps 5GHz, 600Mbps 2.4GHz).
- 2014 MacBook Pro with AC capable Wi-Fi
- 2014 iPhone 6 with AC capable Wi-Fi
- 2016 Asus Zenbook with AC capable Wi-Fi
- CAT6 Ethernet cables

When I connect, via Ethernet, to either of these I get the full 80Mbps down and 10Mbps up.  It's my understanding that, with Wi-Fi, and with my routers both more than capable on either band (even with half-duplex and real-world wi-fi issues), I should be getting those same ISP speeds (or at least close to them) on either the 2.4GHz or 5GHz bands with either router.  However, and this is consistent across all my devices, I will get a max of about 40Mbps (5GHz) down from my Archer C9 router, even if I'm standing near it.  If I stand near my C2100Z, I'll get between 60-70Mbps (better, but not the full 80Mbps).  I know noise is an issue and there are definitely other networks around so I don't really expect to achieve the actual 80Mbps connection, but I feel it should be closer than 40Mbps, especially within feet of the router, and considering that the C2100Z is getting closer to the 80Mbps.  My upload speeds, from either router, on any device, and standing almost anywhere in the house, are almost always 10Mbps (what they should be).

So here are my questions:

1. If my router is rated to give 1.3Gbps Wi-Fi on the 5GHz band, then why (even with half-duplex and other real-world factors) am I only achieving 40Mbps?
2. It's worth noting that, on the 2.4GHz band, I'm only getting about 30Mbps with either router (when standing by the router).  Those speeds are rated at 300Mbps and 600Mbps (for the C2100Z and Archer C9 respectively).  Why aren't those reaching their potential?
3. Why is the 2.4GHz slower than the 5GHz, even if both should be capable of higher than 80Mbps speeds?
4. Why are my upload speeds consistent and maxed out, but my download speeds aren't?

To help narrow down the issue, I've done the following:

- Placed both routers in various locations
- Turned off the radios of the router I wasn't testing (to minimize interference)
- Only connected one device (computer/phone) at a time
- Adjusted the antennas of the Archer C9
- Used multiple devices (see the list above)
- Adjusted the channel frequency and width of both the 5GHz and 2.4GHz
- Set the Archer C9 as an access point
- Set the C2100Z in bridge mode

Even with all of these, I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: Since you've covered 99% of the bases, perhaps a firmware update (if available) is in order?

Comment: I forgot to mention it, but I am updated to the most recent firmware on both devices.

Comment: Some additional datapoints would be useful. Specifically, have you done speed tests between two PCs on your local network (let's remote the Internet connection from the equation for the moment)? Ideally you would try this with one PC on WiFi and one on a wired connection as well as with both on wired and with both on WiFi. You would repeat this with both routers. This would give much more detail to help narrow down the issue. A utility like iperf can be used on local networks for speed testing.

Comment: @BenFranske I did some tests with iperf3 on my MacBook Pro as the server and a 2017 Dell XPS as the client.  I didn't have an ethernet adapter for the Dell, so I could only test it with the Mac.  On the Archer C9 I averaged 81.18Mbps at 5GHz (both wifi), 253.4Mbps at 5GHz (Mac wired), 14Mbps at 2.4GHz (both wifi), 51.45Mbps at 2.4GHz (Mac wired).  On the C2100Z I averaged 70.46Mbps at 5GHz (both wifi), 275.8Mbps at 5GHz (Mac wired), 10Mbps at 2.4GHz (both wifi), 51.34Mbps at 2.4GHz (Mac wired).  If I switched up the server/client it didn't make much of a difference.

Comment: So based on that both routers would appear to have about the same performance. Also, as you can see, when you have more than one client on WiFi at a time you take a serious hit in performance. This is really pretty normal as wireless is a shared medium and greatly susceptible to interference as well as being half-duplex, etc.

Comment: @BenFranske That makes sense.  Do those speeds sound right at all, or are both routers underperforming?  I don't really have a good frame of reference for this.  Also, why would they both test around the same with network transfers, but when speed testing the ISP, the Archer C9 caps at around 40Mbps while the C2100Z hits 60-70Mbps?

Comment: See my full answer I was working on below. RE the difference between the two routers on *Internet* connections (which we didn't really see in the LAN testing) that is likely due to differences in the NAT performance of the routers and is something that varies from one router to another.

Comment: @BenFranske When testing my internet speed I made sure I only had one device connected at a time.  Even then, I live in a townhouse complex where there are dozens of active wi-fi networks around me.  It seems I underestimated the impact of interference on wi-fi speeds.  Thanks for your explanations!  I'd up-vote your answer, but I don't yet have enough reputation to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the testing in the comments here are my most likely answers to your questions:

> 1. If my router is rated to give 1.3Gbps Wi-Fi on the 5GHz band, then why (even with half-duplex and other real-world factors) am I only achieving 40Mbps?

I believe that the "real-world" factors are a bigger influence than you imagine. The combination of interference from other networks, half-duplex nature of wireless, and more than one device connected to the WiFi at a time are conspiring to limit your bandwidth substantially. As you noted with one device attached to the wired network you increased bandwidth from ~80Mbps to ~250Mbps at 5GHz. It's difficult to overstate how much additional devices on WiFi decrease throughput.

> 2. It's worth noting that, on the 2.4GHz band, I'm only getting about 30Mbps with either router (when standing by the router). Those speeds are rated at 300Mbps and 600Mbps (for the C2100Z and Archer C9 respectively). Why aren't those reaching their potential?

In the iperf tests you got even worse than 40Mbps, ~10-14Mbps. This, again, is likely due to the interference from other devices as well as general noise in the 2.4GHz band which is even more crowded than 5GHz. If you took the same router and PCs out to the middle of nowhere you would likely be able to achieve much higher speeds (though still not the 300-600 Mbps that's claimed).

> 3. Why is the 2.4GHz slower than the 5GHz, even if both should be capable of higher than 80Mbps speeds?
>      See above. Essentially more interference. There are many intentional (cordless phones, other WiFi networks, wireless microphones, etc.) and unintentional (microwave ovens, etc.) radiators which impact the 2.4GHz ISM band used by WiFi. All of these things cause dropped packets, retransmissions, etc. which effectively slow down the link and lead to reduced signal strength. Moving closer to the router may help but it's not really a solution as the router will still "hear" all of that interference and the interference will still cause problems, it just has a better signal from the client to work with.
> 4. Why are my upload speeds consistent and maxed out, but my download speeds aren't?
>      Because 10Mbps is slow enough that you never/rarely go below that.

TL;DR As you can see the marketing people at WiFi router companies are more than a little generous in how they advertise the "maximum theoretical speed" the routers operate at. Once you account for half-duplex and multiple devices on the network you have much less to begin with. Then, real-world interference, etc. drops performance even more. Some wireless technologies handle this better than others (e.g. MIMO is better than straight DSSS 802.11b) but in the end all wireless succumbs to these issues which is why wired connections are still the gold standard.